# MPMoviePlayer disappear when clicking on done button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I used `MPMoviePlayerController` to play video. Here is the code.

```
// Getting URL from path
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.moviePlayingTempPath];



// Initialize the movie player view controller with a video URL string
self.playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

// Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.playerVC
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:self.playerVC];

// Register this class as an observer instead
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moveiPlayBackStateChanged:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC];    


[self.playerVC setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];

self.playerVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 648);

[self.view addSubview:self.playerVC.view];

// Start playback
[self.playerVC prepareToPlay];
[self.playerVC play];
```

It works fine in the embedded mode. I have very unusual behavior in full screen mode. When I go full screen and can play the video without any problem. Then I can click the done button and come to the embedded mode without problem.

Problem is occurring when go full screen and single click on forward or backward seeking buttons. Then player stop playing and show activity indicator with loading text. Then If i click the done button then the player disappears forever. I cant figure out exact problem to this. Actually i don't need forward and backward seeking buttons. Can we block seeking or how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by removing and adding the movie player to the view when user switch from full screen.

Here is the full code

```
-(void)continuePlayingFile{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.moviePlayingTempPath];

// Initialize the movie player view controller with a video URL string
self.playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

// Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.playerVC
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:self.playerVC];

// Register this class as an observer instead
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moveiPlayBackStateChanged:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(willEnterFullScreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(willExitFullScreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC];

[self.playerVC setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
self.playerVC.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

self.playerVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 648);

[self.view addSubview:self.playerVC.view];

// Start playback
[self.playerVC prepareToPlay];
[self.playerVC play];
 }





   -(void)willExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)note{
        self.isMovieGoFullScreen = NO;
        if(self.isUserClickNextButton){
            //This is to handle user click on next/previous button and then click done button.
            self.isUserClickNextButton=NO;
            [self continuePlayingFile];
        }
    }

    -(void)moveiPlayBackStateChanged:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
        if(self.playerVC){
            self.currentPlayerState = self.playerVC.playbackState;
           if(self.currentPlayerState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped){
                self.isUserClickNextButton =YES;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when adding the observer, the object parameter should be playerVC.moviePlayer and not the playerVC.

The moviePlayer (class MPMoviePlayerController) is the one sending the notification.

So change this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayerVC];
```

to this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayerVC.moviePlayer];
```